# How to execute a bat file inside exe? (exe created using WinRAR sfx)

Tags: windows, installation, exe, winrar, sfx

I want to create an exe file which includes mysql.msi and java.zip. I have written vbscript to install mysql and extract java file in C: drive. It works fine.

Now my problem is:

Convert the source folder as exe by using WinRAR sfx option.

How can I execute the vbscript or bat file (for executing vbscript) when I click the created exe?

Has anybody a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFX commands: `Setup` i.e., `Setup = <program>`

SFX will try to execute  after successful extraction. The folder containing extracted files is set as the current before executing . If a program name contains spaces, it must be enclosed in quotes.
**Example**

`Setup = setup.exe`

Comment: follow this link : http://www.jackmccarthy.com/malware/WinRAR_Archive_Creation.htm

Comment: does this work for non-executable stuff? e.g. will Setup=home.html open the file in default browser?

Comment: @tumchaaditya Right now, I don't have access to windows machine(I'm on my Linux machine), why don't you try it yourself .. sorry for being not so helpful .. Have a Good day!

Comment: @tumchaaditya For getting opened a file not being an executable by the application registered as default application for the file according to file extension create a batch file with first line being `start "" "File To Open"` and second line being `del "%~f0"` and add this batch file to the archive and specify this batch file as executable to run after extraction. The batch file opens the file in default application (browser for *.htm) using command __start__ and then deletes itself.