# How to get WinRar SFX to launch a bat file after extraction

Tags: winrar, sfx

So I need to get the SFX to extract to the location and then automatically launch the bat file from the folder it's just extracted to.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 8):

In started *WinRAR* select the files or folders to put into an archive and click on button **Add**. Check option *Create SFX archive*.

Switch to tab **Advanced** and click on button **SFX options**. Switch to tab **Setup** and enter in field below *Run after extraction* the name of the batch file, with relative path if the batch file is not in root of the archive.

Click on button **Help** for details on this option.

Switch to tab **Comment** after finishing configuration of all SFX options and pressing button **OK**. You can see there now something like

```
;The comment below contains SFX script commands

Setup=Install.bat
```

You can save all options set for the creation of the SFX archive into a profile for making it easy to run *WinRAR* from within a batch file using the profile or quickly selecting the profile from within GUI.

It is of course also possible to define all settings directly on command line without using a *WinRAR* profile stored in Windows registry for current user.

The manual for the console version `Rar.exe` is the text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR*.

The commands and options available for `WinRAR.exe` are documented in help of *WinRAR*. On tab **Contents** there is **Command line mode** listing all help pages useful to build the command line. For the switches start with **Alphabetic switches list**.

**Edit:**

If `Install.bat` is added to archive in a subfolder, it is necessary to specify the batch file with `subfolder\Install.bat` in **Setup** dialog of **SFX options** respectively the comment file.

And inside the batch file the command line `cd "%~dp0"` must be added at top to change current directory from target directory of extraction set by SFX module to the extracted subfolder containing the batch file.

By the way: Command processor of Windows does not allow execution of a batch file using a UNC path. So it is not possible to run the included batch file when the user chooses to extract the archive to a share on network using a UNC path.

See also

- [How can I create an auto-executing, WinRar SFX file from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183621/)
- [How to execute a bat file inside exe? (exe created using WinRAR sfx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638960/)
- [How to create self-extracting RAR archive not showing anything on execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698055/)

and other topics listed on this page on right side below **Related**.

Comment: I have given this a go but the batch file does not operate correctly, it needs to launch from the actual folder it's been extracted to which I think might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%~dp0`. This represents the directory the batch file is running from.

```
echo %~dp0
```

should print the directory in question.

```
echo Hello World >%~dp0\HelloWorld.txt
```

This will create a HelloWorld.txt file in the directory the batch is ran from.